# Java expecting "Class Name { () {". Note the first {

Tags: java

I just finished doing a Lab Test for my Programming Professor. However my code wouldn't compile due to the error I mentioned in the title. I ran out of time and needed to submit the test anyway. I am curious if anyone here knows what the problem is. I couldn't see a problem but OnlineGDB (Online Compiler as my version of Eclipse kept crashing) would give me these errors.

`Expecting { in class Name^() {`: Note that it wanted the { where the ^ is.

I previously tried doing it the way it wanted only for it to spit out more errors at me that made no sense.

```
public class EnterName() {

    void Name() {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the movie:\n")
        this.Name = input.nextLine();
    }
}//End EnterName();
```

Comment: you are missing a ; after your System.out statement, and you must remove the () after the classname

Comment: `public class EnterName() {`: remove the `()`, they are not valid for a Java class declaration

Comment: @ernest_k don't you mean 'invalid' ?

Comment: get your basics right about java then come back on SO

Comment: Also: *Expecting { in class Name^() {*, but your class' name is `EnterName` -> please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Stultuske I do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
public class EnterName() {

    void Name() {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the movie:\n")
        this.Name = input.nextLine();
    }
}//End EnterName();
```

to this:

```
public class EnterName {

    void Name() {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the movie:\n");
        this.Name = input.nextLine();
    }
}//End EnterName();
```

the "()" after EnterName dont belong there

you missed a ";" after "System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the movie:\n")"

Comment: are you sure that , this.Name = input.nextLine();  is valid here ??

Comment: no idea, doesnt relate to his question so i left it in there

Comment: also i assume he didnt show the entire code either. so it's best left in there for now

Comment: I know that I forgot a " ; " after my System.out.println but that was fine it was in the code this is just a quick markup. The error has been solved thank you.